# How to check if columns are being used by views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, shell, powershell

I have an excel sheet with list of columns mentioned in it. I would now like to know what all columns present in the excel sheet are being used by the views in sql(working in ssms).
The data in excel is just the list of column names.
It looks like.

***ColumnNames***

DimCurrencyId

Dimzoneid

.......

Nearly 1000 column names.

Now I need to find whether if these are being used in sql views or not?

i have nearly 500 views
Can anyone please let me know the simplest way to do this so that i can skip the lot of manual work?

Comment: In short i want to list all the database views that depends on any of the columns i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a much more elegant way to do this, but what I would do is use the Excel file to generate a list of SQL statements, then copy and paste them into SQL Server Management Studio and execute the entire list.

Assuming your column names begin in cell `A2` I would put the following formula in cell `B2` (or the next available column):

```
="select distinct sys.all_views.name from sys.all_views join sys.all_columns on sys.all_views.object_id = sys.all_columns.object_id where sys.all_columns.name = '"&A2&"' union"
```

OR, without needing a join (from [ElenaDBA's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812278/elenadba) answer):

```
="SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name] FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE  VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%"&A2&"%' UNION"
```

Drag the formula down to the end of your list of columns.

Copy and paste the resulting SQL statements into SSMS and be sure to remove the trailing `union` at the very end (the last query won't be unioning anything and you'll get an error if you try to execute the SQL with a trailing `union` statement).

Execute the SQL and you should get a list of the names of the views. `Union` automatically eliminates duplicates.

Again, not elegant, but I believe that will get the job done.

### Update

To display the view name and the column name, you can simply add another reference to cells in column `A` to pick up your column as well.  Additionally, we can modify the `WHERE` clause to only look at the `dbo` schema.

For the first formula that would change to (schema_id of `dbo` is 1):

```
="select distinct sys.all_views.name, '"&A2&"' as 'colName' from sys.all_views join sys.all_columns on sys.all_views.object_id = sys.all_columns.object_id where sys.all_columns.name = '"&A2&"'  and schema_id = 1 union"
```

Basically adding the value you are searching for in the where clause to the select part.

The second formula, using the same idea, would look like this (with the schema being referenced by name):

```
="SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name] , '"&A2&"' as 'colName' FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE  VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%"&A2&"%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'  UNION"
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can tell me a way to find the column names as well that are matched by the WHERE clause.

Comment: You just want them returned as part of the SQL query?  The column names are already available in Excel, if I understand correctly, so there is no need to query the tables for them since you already have them.  If you simply want them displayed you can tweak the queries a bit, which I will add to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I want the column names to be displayed as well. Because i want to find only those columns that are matched with views , not all columns are present. Also I want it to be specific only to schema 'dbo'. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I tried this :

select distinct sys.all_views.name AS View_Name, sys.all_columns.name as Column_Name from sys.all_views join sys.all_columns on sys.all_views.object_id = sys.all_columns.object_id where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dbo' and sys.all_columns.name = 'CancellationDtID' union

But i am getting very less number of views. Not resulting in same number of number of views.

And also both of your answers are resulting in different number of rows.

The one provided by  Elena is resulting 43 rows and yours 13 rows.

Comment: I updated my queries to include how to check for just the `dbo` schema.  Unfortunately without knowing how many databases you have, schemas, etc. it is more difficult on my end.  The difference in results comes from the fact that my query will only operate on the active database, whereas the second query should operate on all databases on the server.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE  VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%YourColumnName%'
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can tell me a way to find the column names as well that are matched by the WHERE clause