# How to find what columns of the views of dbo schema have -1 in place of NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a list of column names of all the views in a excel scheet. How to find what all columns for these views relating to dbo schema have the value -1 in place of null?
basically I understand we must use a cross product between the column names in excel and the views in db to get the columns that views are using. for that my query looks like this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name] 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE  table_schema = 'dbo' and 
VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%DimCurrencyId%' 
UNION
SELECT TABLE_NAME as [View Name] 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE  table_schema = 'dbo' and 
VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%DimTimeZoneId%'
UNION 
.........
```

I want to improve this query result to show the columns of the views as well and show which of them are given -1 in place of null Group by the view name.

My result should look like

```
viewName   ColumnName
xxxx        xxxx
xxxx        xxxx
```

Comment: Are you asking about the data in the table or just the default value of the column?

Comment: The only way to find out is to ask the person who created the database.   It's the only way to know whether a -1 is a -1, or is a replacement for NULL.

Comment: recently someone changed few tables, in which they replaced NULL with -1 and we have no contact of him, may be he left.

Comment: @TTeeple : I m asking about data in which previously it was NULL now changed to -1. want to find all the tables in which there is no data we have -1 now

Comment: If there is no data, how do you have -1?  Or do you mean just search all tables and columns for the value of -1?  It has been done before but it is all dynamic SQL and pretty messy.

Comment: @TTeeple
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972210/how-to-check-if-columns-are-being-used-by-views

In the above problem for the answer given, I also want the column names not just view names. Probably that gives me the answer. Can you help me with that ?